# Adafruit PIOLED 128x32 not being detected

Tags: i2c, pi-zero-w

I've searched around on this forum and other places for similar issues, but nothing has helped so far.

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero W and I bought the [Adafruit PIOLED 128x32](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pioled-128x32-mini-oled-for-raspberry-pi/overview).  I have header pins on the pi and I have the PIOLED plugged into (not soldered) the first 6 pins exactly as shown in the promotional images, like this:
[image: PIOLED on raspberry pi zero w]

I followed the two guides [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pioled-128x32-mini-oled-for-raspberry-pi/usage) and [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c)

Running `sudo i2cdetect -y 1` gives me nothing, and running the [b]stats.py[/b] example script produces I/O errors.

[image: i2cdetect results]

Have I missed something or done something wrong?  I've seen other adafruit forum posts request to see the underside of the PIOLED in case the connections are bad, so here's that image.

[image: PIOLED underside]

*([cross-posted on the adafruit forum](https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?t=125913))*

Answer (score 0):

Use jumper wires between the I2C device and the Pi or solder in place.

I2C needs a stable connection.